# What is cpts/ in var/log/lastlog

Tags: ubuntu, login, logging

I've tried to cat /var/log/lastlog and it only opens with a single line with:

```
▒▒▒cpts/4192.168.1.111
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've worked it out, it's a reference to the last login

`cpts/4`- refers to the port

`192.168.1.111`- refers to the IP

concated  `cpts/4192.168.1.111`

Answer (score 0):

`/var/log/lastlog` is a binary file consisting of fixed-size records (C structs) – it is not a text file and trying to 'cat' it will not be very useful. Use the `lastlog` command to read it instead.

`pts/4` and `192.168.1.111` are values of string fields *ll_line* and *ll_host* (they are not actually concatenated – they are NUL-padded, your terminal just doesn't show NUL as anything), while the `c` is part of the timestamp field stored in binary; its real value is byte 0x63, not the letter "c".

(The definition of "struct lastlog" can be found in /usr/include.)